# Chilikat UnlockComponent (sometimes) returns 0 without LastErrorText

Tags: vb6, chilkat

please excuse my poor English... my title allready says the question.
We are using the VB6.0 Server.CreateObject("Chilkat_9_5_0.Crypt2") object with a purchased license in 2017.

What could be the reason the unlock component sometimes stopped working on two different servers at the same time? There is no lastErrorText given, but return value is 0.

The first time it happened in 2018-12-03. Since then till now we had 130 UnlockComponent request with 74 fails and 66 passes.

This random behavoir makes me thinking there is a problem with either a windows update or within the unlock component itself.

any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A Chilkat license (unlock code) is valid for 1 year of new version updates.  You probably downloaded and started using a version that was released more than one year after the license was purchased..